# Is there a way to change cell color in table depending on condition in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I would to change the color of cell in table depending on condition. How could I do that?
This is my code:

HTML page:

```
<table style="margin: 3px">
        <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #7cc3a97d">
          <th class="text-center">Query/File name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Cosine similarity</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for key, value in cosineResults.items() %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ select_query|safe }} / {{ key|safe }} </td>
            {% if value|float > 0.7 %}
                <td class="bg-danger"> {{ value|safe }} </td>
            {% elif value|float > 0.3 %}
                <td class="bg-warning"> {{ value|safe }} </td>
            {% else %}
                <td>{{ value|safe }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It always takes the first condition (> 0.3) even if the value is smaller.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use `0.3` instead of `0,3`. also the way you ordered your if conditions, if `value` is 1 it wont go to the  `> 0.7` section.

Comment: @ilias-sp I edited my code changing the order of if condition. However your solution works very well, thank you so much =)